# How to delete elements with condition below for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello i have a code like this :

```
def remove_something (token):
    temp_token = token
    for t in token :
        if len(t) == 5:
            temp_token.remove(t)
    return temp_token
    
a = ['abcde','abcde','abcde','ef','ghi']
print(remove_something(a))
```

That output should be like this :

`['ef', 'ghi']`

But why like this ? :

`['abcde', 'ef', 'ghi']`

Comment: `temp_token = token` doesn't make a copy of the list. You're removing from the same list you're iterating over.

Comment: Why not use a list comprehension? `return [t for t in token if len(t) != 5]`

Comment: Also this is a good explanation why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/8067109

Answer (score 0):

Use `.copy()` in order to make a copy of a certain variable. This way you can modify this copy without modifying the original variable.

```
def remove_something (token):
    temp_token = token.copy()
    for t in token :
        if len(t) == 5:
            temp_token.remove(t)
    return temp_token
    
a = ['abcde','abcde','abcde','ef','ghi']
print(remove_something(a))
```

output

```
['ef', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
a = ['abcde','abcde','abcde','ef','ghi']
b = [x for x in a if len(x) != 5]
print(b)
# ['ef', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List comprehension

```
  x = [token for token in a if len(token) != 5 ]
  print(x)

output
['ef', 'ghi']
```